# How to generate a matrix to store all non-empty subsets of a set

Tags: r, matrix, while-loop, subset

Suppose I have a set N={1,2,3}, then we can list all its 7 non-empty subsets.

```
    n=3 # number of elements in a set
    a=2^n-1 # number of non-empty subsets for that set
    subsets=lapply(1:n, function(x) combn(n, x)) # list all the non-empty subest
    subsets
```

Now I want to put these subsets into a matrix and organized like:

```
    if n=3     or in an index matrix:    
    1 0 0      1 0 0
    0 2 0      0 1 0
    0 0 3      0 0 1

    1 2 0      1 1 0
    1 0 3      1 0 1
    0 2 3      0 1 1

    1 2 3      1 1 1
```

Anyone knows how to write the code that could be easily extended to any n (=4, 5, 6...)? I tried this:

```
    subindex=matrix(c(0), nrow=a, ncol=n)

    i=1
      while(i<=a){

       j=n
       b=2^(n-1)
       N=i
          while(N>0){
             if(b<=N) {subindex[i,j]=1}&{N=N-b}
             b=trunc(b/2)
             j=j-1
          }

       i=i+1
       }
      subindex
```

But the index matrix I get is wrong in row 3 and 4. If n=4, then there are more errors... Can anybody correct this or simplify this code? or just write a completely new code. Really appreciate.

Comment: downvote seems a bit unjustified, no?

Comment: Yeah. I think I did it by accident on the freeway. It won't let me reverse it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n <- 4
lapply(seq_len(n), function(i)t(combn(n, i, FUN = tabulate, nbins = n)))

# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    1    0
# [3,]    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    0    1    1    0
# [5,]    0    1    0    1
# [6,]    0    0    1    1
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0
# [2,]    1    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    0    1    1
# [4,]    0    1    1    1
# 
# [[4]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: what could I say...@_@~~ Orz...tearing with appreciation and worship. Thank you so much @flodel